# Query to return 24 month sales history, ,by month, using month() in where clause is returning current year results multiple times

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2014

I want to report sales, by month, for the past 24 months.  Next month the 25th month set of numbers should drop off the report and reflect the last 24 months again.  I'm not sure how to write the query to handle the year change.  Here is what I have.

```
select  [Amount] * -1 as 'Parts Not Sold On Service Order Current', 0 as 'Parts Sold     On Service Order', [Document Date]
from    [G_L Entry]
where   [G_L Account No_] between '40000' and '49999'
and     [Dimension code] = 'par'
and     [Document No_] not like 'PSV%'
AND     YEAR([Document Date]) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
AND     MONTH([Document Date]) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

union

    select  [Amount] * -1 as 'Parts Not Sold On Service Order Current -1', 0 as 'Parts Sold     On Service Order', [Document Date]
from    [G_L Entry]
where   [G_L Account No_] between '40000' and '49999'
and     [Dimension code] = 'par'
and     [Document No_] not like 'PSV%'
AND     YEAR([Document Date]) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
AND     MONTH([Document Date]) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -1

union

    select  [Amount] * -1 as 'Parts Not Sold On Service Order Current -2', 0 as 'Parts Sold     On Service Order', [Document Date]
from    [G_L Entry]
where   [G_L Account No_] between '40000' and '49999'
and     [Dimension code] = 'par'
and     [Document No_] not like 'PSV%'
AND     YEAR([Document Date]) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
AND     MONTH([Document Date]) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -2
```

This starts repeating the same year results after going into the previous year.  Month may only be 5 months since the previous year. Next month will be 6 months.  How do I write the query to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your query working the way you want it to in every other aspect already, try adding the following to your `WHERE` statements:

```
AND DateDiff(Month, [Document Date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 24
```

You may have to play with it a bit to get it just right for your particular report (e.g., "< 23", "< 25", etc)

I'm not a mind-reader, but integrating this into your current `WHERE` statement may give you what you want and shorten your query to the following (without your `union`s):

```
select  [Amount] * -1 as 'Parts Not Sold On Service Order Current', 0 as 'Parts Sold On Service Order', [Document Date]
from    [G_L Entry]
where   [G_L Account No_] between '40000' and '49999'
and     [Dimension code] = 'par'
and     [Document No_] not like 'PSV%'
AND     DateDiff(Month, [Document Date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 24
```

Comment: Boom!!  Perfect.  I can break the months down within the reporting software.  Thanks.  I'd like to learn much more on date time functions.  Any good articles on here or elsewhere to recommend?

Comment: @Craig Zirnheld, Sorry, I don't know of any good tutorial-style ones.  I just read through [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) for SQL Server-type questions 99% of the time.